# 'FileNotFoundError' When Running R From Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to run some R from python but I keep running into:

'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'

I have tried searching for this problem but none of the solutions have worked.
The files are in the same directory and I'm running windows.
Here is my attempt the python:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from os import path


myfile = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "test.R")

cmd = ['Rscript', myfile]


result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)

print(result)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The R code is just a simple Hello World.

Comment: Is `Rscript` added to path variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that you have added `Rscript` to path variable. Use below code to change your working directory as current directory

```
import subprocess
import sys
from os import path

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "."))
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

myfile = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "test.R")

cmd = ['Rscript', myfile]


result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)

print(result)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I forgot to add Rscript to path, sorry for the trouble!